# Can Eureka Clients discover the Server without an explicit URL?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

In a sample Spring Boot project I've setup, I point my Eureka clients to my Eureka server with a URL like so:
`eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8761/eureka/v2/`

I'm worried about what happens if the Eureka Server dies.

As a remedy, is there a way to setup multiple instance of Eureka Server and configure the Eureka Clients to discover them (w/o relying on an absolute URL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka framework support multiple Eureka Server instance. The client choose a server while initialization and propose request to the server until the server dies.

For example, if you start two eureka Servers locally on port 8761 and 8762 with same configuration :

```
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8761/eureka/v2/,http://localhost:8762/eureka/v2/
```

And your client app should also got the same configuration of `eureka.serviceUrl.default`; When the app start up, it will choose `localhost:8761` as eureka server and send register request to `localhost:8761`, then `localhost:8761` will record and send a same register request to `localhost:8762`; when `localhost:8761` dies, the client app will switch to `localhost:8762` to send heartbeat requests.